# strcomp not working with ms sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vb6

Code used for login using `ms access` and it is working fine . But, I need to change the database to `ms sql 2008` and in `sql strcomp` does not work. So, do I need alternative  of `strcomp` in `sql` or how can I make this below code working with `ms sql` database?

```
Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT * FROM Users where StrComp(UserName, '" & sfindtext & "', 0) = 0")

If rs.EOF Then
    recfound = False
Else
  With rs
    recfound = True
     UserID = !UserID
     Username = !Username
     Password = !UPassword
     Privilege = !Privilege
  End With
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to check the value of the `sfindtext`:

```
Set rs = con.Execute("
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
where (case when UserName = '" & sfindtext & "' then 0 else 1 end) = 0")
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e62b/2) of the query working

Or you don't even need the logic `CASE` piece:

```
Set rs = con.Execute("
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
where UserName = '" & sfindtext & "'"
```